# how to use regex with 2 element to replace?

Tags: javascript, regex, next.js

I have a string of characters that i want to amend partially by adding a span tag highlighting  the words by changing the color. I have a regex that matches 2 different pattern that i am targeting. I can only change the first pattern like i want to but not the other one.
Can someone help please?

```
let regex = /make your life easier|forget about the “I have to’s”/gi,

let aboutUsText3:
    "We have more than 10 years’ experience in the sector and can offer you a professional and comprehensive real estate service. We’re here to [make your life easier], so that you can forget about the [“I have to’s”]. We can give you advice on whatever you need, whether it’s refurbishments, interior design, decoration, rental management, valuation of investments, or anything else. We’re here for you.",

 const spannedText2 =
    locale === "es"
      ? es.aboutUsText3
      : aboutUsText3.replace(
          regex.t3,
          [
            `<span class="fw-bold text-span">${strEnToSpan[2]}
          </span>`,
            `<span class="fw-bold text-span">${strEnToSpan[3]}</span>`,
          ].shift()
        );
```

when i call the spannedText function only one element is highlighted.
what would be the best way to achieve this?

the output should be as follow:

```
<p>We have more than 10 years’ experience in the sector and can offer you a professional and comprehensive real estate service. We’re here to <span classname="bold">make your life easier</span>, so that you can forget about the <span classname="bold">“I have to’s”</span>. We can give you advice on whatever you need, whether it’s refurbishments, interior design, decoration, rental management, valuation of investments, or anything else. We’re here for you.",<P>
```

Comment: Note that using regex to manipulate HTML content is not such good practice.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. I don't know how to resolve this issue. i have  a string that i want to partially highlight. Do you have a tip for me? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Please add sample input text to your question, then show us what the output should be.  You may want multiple examples, to demo how the alternation in your regex is supposed to be behaving.

Comment: You have `[“I have to’s”]`in your text. Obviously that won't match.

Comment: @PoulBak it is for you guys to see where is the target words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A Simple Alternative**

In your example the sections to be highlighted are wrapped in brackets:

```
[text to be highlighted]
```

So you could just match the brackets and replace them with a span. This would be much easier to maintain and make work with multiple languages.

The regex matches the brackets and captures the text within:

```
/\[(.*?)\]/g
```

And we surround the [captured text $1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n) with a span:

```
text.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, `<span class="bold">$1</span>`);
```

You might also want to look at using a JavaScript markdown library like [Marked.js](https://marked.js.org/) for more complex text transformations.

**Run the snippet to understand how it works**

```js
function setLocale(locale) {

  let text = locale === "es" ? aboutUsText.es : aboutUsText.en;

  aboutUs.innerHTML = text.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, `<span class="bold">$1</span>`);
  
}

let aboutUsText = {

en: `We have more than 10 years’ experience in the sector and can offer you a professional and comprehensive real estate service. We’re here to [make your life easier], so that you can forget about the [“I have to’s”]. We can give you advice on whatever you need, whether it’s refurbishments, interior design, decoration, rental management, valuation of investments, or anything else. We’re here for you.`,

es: `Contamos con más de 10 años de experiencia en el sector y podemos ofrecerle un servicio inmobiliario profesional e integral. Estamos aquí para [hacer tu vida más fácil], para que te olvides de los [“tengo que”]. Podemos asesorarte en lo que necesites, ya sean reformas, interiorismo, decoración, gestión de alquileres, valoración de inversiones, o cualquier otro. Estamos aquí por tí.`

};


setLocale("en");
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="locale" value="en" onchange="setLocale(this.value)" checked> English
<input type="radio" name="locale" value="es" onchange="setLocale(this.value)"> Español
<p id="aboutUs"></p>
```